# Comparing different fractions for ranking?

Tags: reference-request, fractions, percentages

I have collected data from thousands of citizens living in 5 different countries regarding their opinion about a topic.

For example in Country A, I have 2975 respondents, 1444 respondents answered positively and 1531 answered negatively.

In Country B, I have 2775 respondents, 1376 respondents answered positively and 1399 respondents answered negatively etc.

I want to assemble the countries in descending order with the countries with the most positive answers closer the top and the least positive answers closer to the bottom. The problem is that every country has a different amount of respondents so I can't confidently say that Country A (1444/2975) is more optimistic than Country B (1376/2775).

Any suggestions and academic papers relating to this problem would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can't you simply use the proportions 1444/2975 = 0.485 and 1376/2775 = 0.496 etc to rank?

Comment: @Paul I'm pretty bad at maths so I wasn't sure. Thanks Paul!